# How do you use a regex in a list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to locate all index positions of a string in a list of words and I want the values returned as a list. I would like to find the string if it is on its own, or if it is preceded or followed by punctuation, but not if it is a substring of a larger word.

The following code only captures "cow" only and misses both "test;cow" and "cow."

```
myList = ['test;cow', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'cow.', 'cow', 'acow']
myString = 'cow'
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if x == myString]
print indices
>> 5
```

I have tried changing the code to use a regular expression:

```
import re
myList = ['test;cow', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'cow.', 'cow', 'acow']
myString = 'cow'
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if x == re.match('\W*myString\W*', myList)]
print indices
```

But this gives an error: expected string or buffer

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong I'd be very happy to hear. I have a feeling it's something to do with the fact I'm trying to use a regular expression in there when it's expecting a string. Is there a solution?

The output I'm looking for should read:

```
>> [0, 4, 5]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need to assign the result of `match` back to `x`. And your match should be on `x` rather than `list`.

Also, you need to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`, since your the regex pattern `'\W*myString\W*'` will not match the first element. That's because `test;` is not matched by `\W*`. Actually, you only need to test for immediate following and preceding character, and not the complete string.

So, you can rather use `word boundaries` around the string:

```
pattern = r'\b' + re.escape(myString) + r'\b'
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if re.search(pattern, x)]
```

Answer (score 7):

There are a few problems with your code. First, you need to match the expr against the list element (`x`), not against the whole list (`myList`). Second, in order to insert a variable in the expression, you have to use `+` (string concatenation). And finally, use raw literals (`r'\W`) to properly interpet slashes in the expr:

```
import re
myList = ['test;cow', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'cow.', 'cow', 'acow']
myString = 'cow'
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if re.match(r'\W*' + myString + r'\W*', x)]
print indices
```

If there are chances that myString contains special regexp characters (like a slash or a dot), you'll also need to apply `re.escape` to it:

```
regex = r'\W*' + re.escape(myString) + r'\W*'
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if re.match(regex, x)]
```

As pointed out in the comments, the following might be a better option:

```
regex = r'\b' + re.escape(myString) + r'\b'
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if re.search(regex, x)]
```

Comment: Maybe add `re.escape` too?

Comment: This doesn't match the first element, which OP want to match.

Comment: Another issue is that the regex doesn't actually provide the output the OP expects (it doesn't match `test;cow`, for example). I think `re.search(r'\b' + myString + r'\b', x)` might work.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ran into trouble with the r'\b*' which was returning the error "nothing to repeat", as noted in the comment above.

Comment: @Adam: yeah, my bad, should be `\b` not `\b*`.