# In Python, how to check if a string match one of the regex in array `efficiently`?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I know there is already some threads about matching regex in array: [How do you use a regex in a list comprehension in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819164/how-do-you-use-a-regex-in-a-list-comprehension-in-python)  But I don't think these approaches are very scalable.

My question is how to do the regex matching as efficiently as possible. For example, I have a profanity word list below (It has 2000 lines in total):

```
.*damn
bollock.*
...
```

(You get the idea…)

What I want to do is to find whether a sentence contains any profanity word/pattern as fast as possible. Concatenate all this pattern into a pattern by using `|` will lead to a super-huge pattern.. Does anyone have ideas about how to optimize it in Python?

Comment: Beware the [Scunthorpe problem…](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)

Comment: I don't know who downvotes this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Likely due to the gratuitous use of profanity in the original post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will give it a try for this library:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/esmre/

> Regular expression acceleration in Python using Aho-Corasick

Or this:

https://github.com/WojciechMula/pyahocorasick/